# datepicker applies to wrong field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm facing a little problem with my jQuery UI datepicker.
The thing is, I have my page and some input like this :

```
blabla | blabla | .date-picker | blabla
blabla2 | blabla2 | .date-picker | blabla2
blabla3 | blabla3 | .date-picker | blabla3
```

So the 'blabla' are just some text, and the '.date-picker' is an input, with the 'date-picker' class.

In my JavaScript code I have just the following :

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker();
});
```

But for example, if I click on the input of the line "blabla3", instead of updating the right input, it always updates the first one...

My input have all the same id (I can't change it), but I'm using the class of the input for my selector, so it should work but doesn't.

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same ID is invalid and we cannot control the behaviour of anything if you choose to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Hello old post but it's for those who are still facing this problem...

Just remove the `id` of the new input, datepicker always generates a new id i.e. if the input doesn't have one. If it had one the datepicker would keep that, which mean here the first input was cloned and the last will also be updated.

Comment: Tested and this is correct, once I removed the ID field a unique one is generated by date picker, thank you!!

Comment: The important bit of information here is that datepicker "generates an new id if the input doesn't have one".  This wasn't a problem if the page was loading even if the datepicker fields were dynamically created during loading, but if you added a datepicker element after page load, the selection would go into the wrong field.  Removing unnecessary input ID fields that get duplicated during dynamic creation,  solves the problem - I just wish I could get the last day back trying to figure out what was wrong :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should change the id of your inputs, else it will not work, because, when you select any date, it use  `DP_jQuery_1347006322116.datepicker._selectDay('#same',8,2012, this);return false;` this function to selectDay, and it is taking the id for the input.

so if you have multiple id, it will select first input and set the day there.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation ! There is really no possibility in order to do that without changing the id's ? Because the PHP code behind the form will have to change completely if I change the id's of my input... Before on my page, I was using the datepicker to select only year and month, with this code : http://pastebin.com/rnDSKnvp
And it was working great.

Is there any solution to add the day in the code above ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem wherein I would use javascript to dynamically add new DIV containers containing date fields with the same ID tags.  The only method for solving in my case was to dynamically rewrite all IDs then destroy/create the datepicker functionality:

```
var n=0;    
$("[id*='blabla']").each(function(){
    n++;
    tempField = this.id.split("-");
    this.id = tempField[0]+"-"+n;
    });

// first remove datepicker functionality since renaming of id above then            
// add datepicker to any field with "datepicker" as class   

    $("input.datepicker").datepicker("destroy").datepicker();
```

I modified the above to fit your use case (I think).  Hope this helps.

BTW: The reason I am splitting by a hyphen ("-") is because I can then call this function every time I dynamically create another DIV container with datepicker fields.  It will systematically rename all the IDs in sequential order for later form processing.

Comment: man i almost want to downvote that one due its hack-the-core nature, and ugly code.. lol.  I think theres a better way for sure, and would not be happy with this implementation

Comment: This worked for me, but only after I put the destroy/create in a $('.datepicker').each(function() That is to say, I needed to destroy and then recreate for all the dateinputs